# Having trouble comparing multiple columns and rows in different worksheets in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I have limited knowledge of formulas in excel and would really appreciate help with this question:

I have two worksheets: Worksheet1 and Worksheet2. Worksheet A1 shows a list of all the samples that are in a lab, and Worksheet2 shows a list of only the samples in the lab that have been analyzed and have results. Column A in both worksheets is the lab #, but as just mentioned column A in Worksheet1 contains all the lab numbers of the samples in the lab, and column A in Worksheet2 contains the lab numbers of only the analyzed samples. Some samples have 2 analysis methods so they appear twice in column A in Worksheet2. Three types of analysis were performed: U/Pb, At/At, and K/Ar; these correspond to columns B, C, D in Worksheet1 respectively. Column B in Worksheet2 names the type of analysis performed. I need to fill out columns B, C and D in Worksheet1 the following way:

First of all, I need to compare column A in Worksheet1 to column A in Worksheet2; if the lab number value in A in Worksheet1 appears in A in Worksheet2, then look at column B in Worksheet2 to check what kind of analysis was done. If analysis U/Pb was done, fill the respective cell in Worksheet1 with YES or "(blank)" for that analysis type; i.e. if analysis U/Pb and K/Ar was done for sample 427, then YES should appear in column B and D, columns C should be blank. If analysis K/Ar was done for sample 482 then YES should appear in columns D and B and C should be blank.

I've included a screenshot of the worksheets:

[image: Worksheet1]

[image: Worksheet2]

Answer (score 0):

Fill in sheet A1 cell B2 with:

```
=IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,'A2'!$A:$B,2,FALSE)="U/Pb","FALSE"),"YES","")
```

Cell C2 with:

```
=IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,'A2'!$A:$B,2,FALSE)="Ar/Ar","FALSE"),"YES","")
```

Cell D2 with:

```
=IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,'A2'!$A:$B,2,FALSE)="K/Ar","FALSE"),"YES","")
```

Copy formulas down your sheet.  I guessed at Ar/Ar (At/At?) following the same pattern as the other two.  Please mark as answer if this does the trick for you.